# What will be the output when using pass-by-value-result with parameters such n+1?

Tags: programming-languages

Let's say a function $f$ is called with parameter $n+1$. Since I use pass-by-value-result, value of formal parameter will be transmitted to the caller's actual parameter at the end of the call. Let transmitted value be 10. What will be the value of $n$? 9 ($n+1 = 10$) or still 10?

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot pass $n+1$ as a parameter of type pass-by-value-result. Such a parameter needs an *lvalue*, whereas $n+1$ is an *rvalue*. Another option is that $n+1$ will be computed in a temporary place in memory, and so the compiler won't complain, and the value of $n$ won't change. The exact behavior could depend on the language or compiler.